# How to get name of a temporary table in BigQuery using API

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a query using BigQuery.Jobs.query. I know that this creates a temporary table. I want to get the name of this table to use it in my next query.

This works for me in BigQuery web UI, but I couldn't find a method using API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) endpoint, and once the `state=DONE`, If successful, this method returns a [Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource) resource in the response body.

And there you have under `['configuration']['query']` the project_id, dataset_id and table_id. If you ran an extract then some values are under `['configuration']['extract']`

Comment: Specifically: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable

Answer (score 0):

Your job should return an object when it's done. If you are using Python you will find the table in:

```
query_job._properties["configuration"]["query"]["destinationTable"]
```

It should have the following schema:

```
{"projectId": "YOUR_PROJECT", "datasetId": "YOUR_DATASET", "tableId": "TEMP_ID"}
```

In order to access the table by name you should use the following name:

```
"projectId.datasetId.tableId"
```